# In the Quantum eraser experiment, Why doesn't detector D1 or D2 cause wave function collapse?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, double-slit-experiment, quantum-eraser

I thought measurement at detectors is what collapes the wave function. So why aren't these detectors causing collapse? Why is there an interference pattern?

Comment: You’ll need to define your notation for folks to be able to answer you - are you using the detector IDs from a wiki article?  I’d link if so.

Comment: Whatever setup you're talking about, what makes you think that the wave function doesn't collapse?

Comment: You can find your answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/443482/in-the-double-slit-experiment-of-electrons-observed-by-photons-is-it-correct/443515#443515)

Comment: If you don't have an answer thats ok